# Remove whitespace from the field form

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to remove the whitespace from both sides of the string. 
The string is entered in the field, which is valid: `'str': ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^(?![- ])(?!.*[- ]{2})(?!.*[- ]$)[A-zА-яёЁ() -]+$/)]]`. 
I want to use method `trim()` to remove the whitespaces. How to apply it correctly to the form field?

Answer (score 1):

you could subscribe to the valueChange event:

```
this.formGroup.controls.str.valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
    // emitEvent: false will prevent this change from triggering the value change event again
    this.formGroup.controls.str.setValue(val.trim(), { emitEvent: false };
})
```